# Implement Slide To Open

Tags: android, slide

I want to implement the concept of "Slide to open" concept in my application. Basically, I am using an ImageView. If the user slide it to a specific direction (to the right for example), the next activity is started. I do not know how to implement this in Android, I have searched in lots of place but found nothing.

Any clues ?

What I came into :

- No I do not think that the use of ViewPager or HorizontalScrollView is appropriate in this case.
- I don't know if the concept of Drag And Drop helps (how to imply a drag in a specific direction ? How to let the ImageView return to its initial location if the drag ends midway ? ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use frame layout and put a ImageView in it. Then add touchEvents to Imageview. update imagViews Layout parameters at ON_MOVE event.This is the basic idea of slide and drag stuff in android.Good luck.

you may use View.Animation for moving back the slider to start position again ON_UP event

you can move view only in x axis by only changing the views :

```
 LayoutParams.leftMargin=event.getRawX();
```

(always set the gravity to NO_GRAVITY)

Comment: Why should I use a FrameLayout exclusively ? Can you please explain ? Thank you.

Comment: Because framelayout does not force its child views to stay incide in visible bounds and all its childs may overlay each other(in z order you add).(relative layout forces its childs to stay in visible bounds by changing child view size)

Comment: Thank you Ercan ! I was able to implement what I need thanks to your guiding ! However I did not use the NO_GRAVITY attribute (I do not think it exists).

Comment: LayoutParams .gravity=Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;

Comment: Ah, my bad, I tried to set it from the XML file, on the layout_gravity attribute and did not find it. Anyways I did not use it and it is working perfectly. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement smth like "slide to unlock" you can implement [drag and drop](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/) and forbid moving by Y axis for example. Also you can check image position and analys if this shift is enough to open\unlock, and if not - simple move this image back.

Comment: How can I forbid moving by Y axis ? And how can I move back the image ? Can you please guide me ? Thank you for your prompt reply.

Comment: Check my link, you can find lp.x = touchX - mRegistrationX; and lp.y = touchY - mRegistrationY; you can comment lp.y line =)